# mod_rewrite: remove query string from URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to make the following redirection (301) using .htaccess

> *?page=1 redirects to *

(where * is a wildcard).

Basically, I just want to prevent anyone accessing a page with ?page=1 at the end of the URL, and instead direct them to the same url minus `?page=1`.

Is there a quick way of doing this?

Comment: See this "How to remove query strings from URLs" https://helponnet.com/2021/06/07/remove-specific-query-string-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^page=1$
RewriteRule      (.*)               $1?     [R=permanent]
```

Line by line:

1. You turn on the rewriting functionality.
2. You specify as a condition ("if statement") that the query string has to be exactly `page=1` for the following rules to apply.
3. Then you specify a rule that says substitute the entire path (.*) with itself ($1), but make the query string empty (?), and make the result a permanent redirect (301).

If you want the redirect to be temporary (302) then you can just remove the `=permanent` part. Moved Temporarily is the default for the `R` flag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can't seem to get that working however, it does not seem to have any effect when I try to access ../?page=1 any ideas?

Comment: Check that your server has mod_rewrite loaded, and that your server settings allow you to specify those rewrite settings in a .htaccess file.

Comment: @Fabian - The `RewriteRule` won't match because the input to the test pattern in a per-directory (`.htaccess`) context won't contain a leading slash. I suspect that's the issue here.

Comment: What if there are other queries present and the only one you want to remove is `page=1`? For example: `www.domain.com?a=5&page=1&b=2` becomes `www.domain.com?a=5&b=2?` All queries are retained except that **page=1** gets stripped off.

Comment: @enchance That's a different question, you may want to open a new question for that. But here goes: `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)page=1(.*)$` `RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%2?` – didn't test it but something like that should work.

Comment: Is it possible to remove ? from redirected url?

Comment: I need to add the full URL paths, otherwise it tries to go to the path of the public directory, and "L" so it redirects without continuing: `RewriteRule.   ^(.*)$.   https://www.example.com/$1? 
   L,R=permanent]`

Answer (score 30):

You can also use the `QSD` flag (Query String Discard) to redirect somewhere without passing the query string.

Comment: QSD is available in Apache version 2.4.0 and later: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd

Answer (score 14):

If you are on Apache 2.4 You can simply use the `QSD` (Query String Discard flag) to discard the specific query strings from your destination URL.

Here is an example for Apache 2.4 users:

**Old URL :** - `/foo/bar/?page=1`

**new URL :** - `/foo/bar/`

`.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=1\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,QSD]
```

The Rule above will redirect any URI with `?page=1` to remove the query strings. This example will return 500 error on Apache versions bellow 2.4 as They don't support `QSD`.

On lower versions of Apache, you may use an empty question mark `?` at the end of the destination URL to remove query strings.

An example:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=1\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

The example above works almost on all versions of Apache.

Answer (score 5):

For stripping entire query string this will be enough:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: good answer:D i believe it may also be ``RewriteRule ^ ${REQUEST_URI}?``

Comment: why do we need http//domain.com/ ?