# Url rewriting with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite, query-string

In my PHP web page I want to redirect as follows:

```
header("Location: page2.php?id=$tid");
```

The querystring is needed by page2.php, but I don't want the querystring displayed in the visitor's browser. I thought I could eliminate the querystring using mod_rewrite as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page2\.php page2\.php?
```

This just removes the query string for page2.php (making it behave in a way not desired), and still displays the query string in the browser's url display area.

I found other references on removing querystrings, like [mod_rewrite: remove query string from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url) , but when I add redirection to the rule like [R=permanent], the url displayed by my browser goes from

```
localhost/admin/page2.php?id=123
```

with by a web page that displays just fine, to

```
http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/admin/page2.php
```

where the web page is not loaded, but instead the following is displayed:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. 
It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
9/5/2011 9:57:19 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

How can I redirect to a page that needs a querystring, but hide that querystring from the visitor so that it is not displayed to them by their browser?

Comment: .htaccess and mod_rewrite doesnt generally work well in localhost

Comment: Do you have an alternate method of passing *tid* to page2.php? Secondly, URL rewriting cannot be used to modify the URL displayed in the browser. It is used to translate pretty URLs into ugly ones *internally*.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog article - [Apache RewriteRule and query string](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/)