# Remove the whole query string from url?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to remove the whole query string from the url using this...

```
RewriteRule ^/page /page?
```

But it is not working any reason why this is happening???

Thanks

Comment: hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
RewriteRule ^page page?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^page$
RewriteRule      (.*)               $1?     [R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write your rewrite rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^page /page? [NC,R,L]
```

Remember leading slash `/` is stripped in matching RewriteRule by Apache.