# mod_rewrite: remove query string from end of url URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to make the following redirection (301) using .htaccess for mp3, jpg, jpeg, png & gif files only.

`http://website.com/file.jpg?c=XXXX` is replaced with `http://website.com/file.jpg`

Basically, I want to strip the query (ie. "?c=XXXX") from end of media url's. I want to prevent anyone accessing an image or mp3 with "?c=XXXX" at the end of the URL, and instead direct them to the same file url minus '?c=XXXX'.

Is there a quick way of doing this?

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod_rewrite: remove query string from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule \.(mp3|jpe?g|png|gif)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava This has been a great help!