# Remove query string during a 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to 301 the following url

```
http://www.site.com/reviews/4f64d2862c16bf4ae40000b4?sort=all-positive
```

to

```
http://www.site.com/reviews
```

By using

```
RewriteRule ^reviews/([a-fA-f0-9]+)?$ http://www.site.com/reviews [L,R=301]
```

But that redirects me to

```
http://www.site.com/reviews?sort=all-positive
```

How can I remove all query strings after what was the review id? Basically the question mark and everything after it needs to go. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this RewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^reviews/([a-fA-F0-9]+)?$ http://www.site.com/reviews/$1? [L,R=301]`
The $1 puts the id at the end of the url, the "?" deletes the query.

I have also changed "A-f" to "A-F", but I do not think this is neccessary.

**Edit**
There is already a similar question in SO: [mod_rewrite: remove query string from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url)