# Duplicate pages 301 redirects changing destination url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some dupilcate pages in my Joomla site.

Examples

/80-games

/80-games?start=12

/80-games?start=20

I did a 301 redirect in my .htcaccess for the first one which works fine.

My redirect for /80-games

```
    Redirect 301 /80-games http://www.teach-this.com/esl-games
```

But for /80-games?start=12

The url changes to http://www.teach-this.com/esl-games?start=12

What should my redirect be for /80-games?start=12

Somehow the question mark is causing my destination url to change.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: the ? is the start of parameters given to the webserver (get method). It is actually not part of the URL and therefore, also passed along to the new URL.

Comment: Check these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726439/remove-query-string-during-a-301-redirect and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url

Comment: Thanks for the links, I tried the answers suggested but they didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mod_rewrite` as you cannot manipulate `QUERY_STRING` using `mod_alias` rules.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^80-games/?$ http://www.teach-this.com/esl-games? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Note `?` at the end of target URI that is used to strip out any existing QUERY_STRING in the original URL.

Comment: I added the code under ## Mod_rewrite in use. in my Joomla .htcaccess but the problem didnt go away. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure this is **first rule** in your .htaccess AND test it in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues. Also make sure rule has `http://www.teach-this.com/esl-games?` with `?` in the end.

Comment: You're a star! I put them as the first rule and it worked straight away. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks again. I saw one of the duplicate pages is just marked as / How should I redirect that? Or is that a new thread?

Comment: Yes please create a new question with little more details. I will try to answer if I can.