# redirect using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Edit :

I want to redirect a url

to : `www.example.com/location/sydney`

from:  `www.example.com/rss.php?pickup=sydney`

Problem is i cant get $_GET['pickup'] value from www.example.com/location/sydney and also location will also change for eg: it may be cairns,london etc. I have a file called rss.php in that i will get the value from $_GET['pickup'].
I tried this :- `Redirect /location http://deals.vroomvroomvroom.com.au/rss.php`

but it gives me a url :- `http://deals.vroomvroomvroom.com.au/rss.php/sydney` when i type in the url `www.example.com/location/sydney`

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite or redirect? Do you want the user to see/use a URL like `http://www.example.com/location/sydney` but the code to handle that is index.php with an element for location in the GET? Or are you trying to have requests to `http://www.example.com/?location=sydney` cause the user to end up with `http://www.example.com/location/sydney` in their address bar? Or do you actually want both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place an .htaccess file in the location directory with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) ../index.php?location=$1&e=1 [L,QSA]
```

This assumes that the index.php that you want to use for requests to /location is located in the directory above the location directory

If you also need the redirect (`www.abc.com/?location=sydney` to `www.abc.com/location/sydney`) to work then I think the best way to do that is to add the following to the (separate) .htaccess file located in the DocumentRoot:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)location=([^&]*)(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&e=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/location/%2?%1%3 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have link which is-`www.abc.com/?location=sydney` i want to redirect this to `www.abc.com/location/sydney` also location can be anything.so I should I create `location` folder as well?srry if im wrong im new to this.

Comment: Okay, so if someone puts `www.abc.com/?location=sydney` in a browser address bar, you want the browser to redirect (changing the URL in the address bar) to `www.abc.com/location/sydney` BUT you also want to actually use the file DocumentRoot/index.php to answer that same request as if the request had been for `www.abc.com/?location=sydney` without any Apache rules, right? So basically you want a rewrite AND a redirect, right?

Comment: yes @ghbarratt how to do that ?

Comment: Have a look at what I added to my answer. Let me know if works or not.

Comment: ok @ghbarratt ill try this and let u know

Comment: When i write this :-`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) ../index.php?location=$1 [L,QSA]` its throwing an error->`400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` and when i write this its redirecting properly but `The requested URL /location/Cairns was not found on this server.` its show this message

Comment: Okay, I changed both .htaccess contents in my answer. It is working in my own test environment, but could probably use a tiny tweak or two.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This one

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^location=1$
RewriteRule      (.*)               $1?     [R=permanent]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled mod_rewrite? `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Also what's the output of `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` when you hit refresh?

Comment: sorry i am new to this can you explain this in more details how to check the output?where to check?

Comment: my project is based on php and hosted on linux server

Comment: Well run those commands I listed and tell us the output.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems you might have:

1) Is mod_rewrite enabled? Check with this command: `apache2ctl -M | grep rewrite` – you should see a line similar to `rewrite_module (shared)` if it's enabled. If not – enable it.

2) Do you have permissions to use .htaccess files? Check the configuration for your virtualhost – this should contain the line AllowOverride, similar to this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/your/site/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now in my example mod_rewrite wouldn't work, because AllowOverride is set to None. Check what you need here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride but you basically need to set it to any other valid option, that is not `None`, otherwise Apache will completely ignore `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 0):

> Location can be anything ...I tried follwoing code but its not working.

If you want to redirect *from* `/location.php?location=sydney` *to* `/location/sydney`, your RewriteRule is the wrong way around. Alas, you can't rewrite based on query parameters.

Comment: so what should i do for that ?