# .htaccess rewrite howto

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirect using htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669695/redirect-using-htaccess-file)

Hello there (very simple question),

How to map

```
mydomain/language/somepage
```

To

```
mydomain/somepage.php
```

The physical page being of course mydomain/somepage.php

The idea is that /en/somepage, /fr/somepage, /de/somepage all point to somepage.php (I intend to get the language passed in URL with php).

More specifically I would like that apache understands to SUPPRESS either /fr /en /de from the request URI and deliver the right document, my physical tree not having any /fr /en /de subdirectory : i.e.

```
root/fr/subdir/subsubdir/somepage
```

should be pointing to

```
root/subdir/subsubdir/somepage.php
```

Thank you !

*** EDIT ***

So, I think I get a better idea how URL rewrites work so, I've come to this. It's broken and I actually suck at regular expressions so if somebody could help me sort it out I would love it ! ^^

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ^[a-z]{2}$/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1
```

Explanations : the URL will be passed to apache in the form of

```
root/(fr|de|en|whatever)/document
```

and is (should be) rewritten in the form of/passed to php

```
root/document.php?lang=(fr|de|en|whatever)
```

I hope it's clear enough, TYVM !

Also, being able to pass subdirectories as well like

```
root/(fr|de|en|whatever)/sub/.../document
```

would be very nice. I need further explanations on htaccess for constants for this like %{REQUEST_FILENAME}, %{REQUEST_URI}, ...

TY

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to redirect users to a certain URL in apache, there is this tutorial that should give you a good guideline:

[Apache mod_rewrite](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html)

However, for you website, i think a better approach to take would be use the language option as a query string. I feel this way you could better handle language based sites. For example, if you have localised version of your website for 30 different countries, you will need to do a mod_rewrite for all 30 of them and when you need to update your site, you will have to fix them all. However, if you use a query string. You `somepage.php` could pick up the query string value and based on that render the necessary page.

I think it is easier to implement. (Or maybe it is a wrong way of doing it and I am unaware of the short-comings)