# htaccess Remove Query String on Redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've researched this for awhile now and swear my solution should work according to the following (and hundreds of others here so forgive my duplication):

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url)
[Example 2](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/301-redirect-old-site-dynamic-urls-to-wordpress-permalinks)

I need to remove the query string from a redirect. Old WordPress ?p=### to a new domain/url.

```
Old Url: blog.domain.com/blog/?p=123
New Url: www.domain.com/yada/woohoo/
```

With this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=123$
RewriteRule ^/blog/$ http://www.domain.com/yada/woohoo/?  [L,R=301]
```

I get: http://www.domain.com/yada/woohoo/?p=123

I want: http://www.domain.com/yada/woohoo/

blog.domain.com will be redirected at the DNS level.

What am I missing? The "?" at the end of the rewrite line should remove the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code, the only thing i changed was the first / in blog, and i got it working perfectly, without the querystring
If you're running Apache > 2.4 then you can use the flag QSD, but otherwise, with the ? at the end it works. Is there any other rules there?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=123$
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://www.domain.com/yada/woohoo/?  [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That extra / I had made the difference. All works now. Thanks!

Comment: On further examination. This works for www.domain.com/blog/?p=123 but not for blog.domain.com/blog/?p=123. Using the subdomain returns the same result as before: www.domain.com/yada/woohoo/?p=123.