# Need help redirecting a domain

Tags: linux

How can I redirect the path /blog/xmlrpc.php?rsd to /blog/ in my .htaccess?

I tried the following below but it doesn't work:

Redirect 301 "/blog/xmlrpc.php?rsd" "/blog/"

and this doesn't work either:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/blog/xmlrpc.php.* /blog/ [R=301,L]

The end result is always:

https://www.example.com/blog/?rsd

How can I get this redirect to work so it doesn't end with '?rsd' or anything else.

Comment: I tried this which almost works but always leaves a "?" after the URL.

RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/xmlrpc\.php* /blog/

Comment: The rewrite above works but adds "?rsd" at the end of the new URL

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rsd$
RewriteRule ^/blog/xmlrpc.php.*$ /blog/? [R=301,L]
```

For more details, refer to the first answer (by Fabian) on [this mod_rewrite question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url).

Comment: The code above works however it keeps the "?rsd" at the end of the redirected URL.