# Unable to remove query strings from URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URLs look like `http://example.com/?n=x`. I want the URL to show as `http://example.com/`. I have used to approaches so far and none of them works.

1. First one is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url):

   `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=1$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]`

After the answer below I modified the .htaccess file:

````
 ```RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=(.*)$
 RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]```
````

but it still did not work. Here is the debugging info:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=(.*)$   
This condition was met.


RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]   
The new url is http://example.com/blog/cat/??
Test are stopped, a redirect will be made with status code permanent
```

2. Second approach is:

   `RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSD]`

None of them seem to work.

I have a few more questions:

1. Does rewriting only work if the URL is not typed manually?
2. Can I still access the values of query strings in PHP?
3. What happens when a user copies the rewritten URL?

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is correct if you go to `http://example.com/?n=1`, if I am correct you should change `^n=1$` to `^n=(.*)$`.

And the other questions:

1. It works for all kind. It doesn't matter if it was a robot or a human writing it, when you access a page, `.htaccess` will be read.
2. Yes you can. Use [$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). If you use the htaccess redirection before explained, you will lose them because you are redirecting.
3. What do you mean ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @P0IT10n  The URL is still not rewritten.

Comment: Try adding between `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=(.*)$`, `RewriteBase /`

Comment: If still not working, try see if your `.htaccess` is been read. Use [this](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) to try HTACCESS rules

Comment: I have updated the question to add extra debugging information. :)

Comment: You have used `http://example.com/blog/cat/??` what should be the correct output of that one ?

Comment: The final output is `http://example.com/blog/cat/??`. My original URL was `http://example.com/blog/cat/?n=1`.

Comment: I found the fix to the `??`, change this `RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]` to this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=permanent]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115363/discussion-between-p0lt10n-and-sanjeet-singh).