# Problems removing query string from url in Prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I've got a prestashop website using `xpert` blog module for blog posts. The problem is that all posts' urls end up with:

```
.html?page_type=post
```

I need to avoid or hide these query string via `.htaccess`. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite: remove query string from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page_type=post\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```