# Redirect 301 all old Subdomain to new Subdomain .htaccess

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need some help. I would like to redirect oldsubdomain.example.com + all folders to newsubdomain.example.com.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsubdomain.example.com$ [NC].
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newsubdomain.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

or

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/?$ https://newsubdomain.example.com/`.

This code works, only problem is that `oldsubdomain.example.com/index.php?id=20` redirects to `newsubdomain.example.com/?id=20` and gives `HTTP ERROR 404`. How to modify the code so that `oldsubdomain.example.com/index.php?id=1-20` redirects to `newsubdomain.example.com`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mod\_rewrite: remove query string from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457022/mod-rewrite-remove-query-string-from-url)